# Как сделать чтобы подзапрос с агрегацией отрабатывал построчно для группировки?

Tags: mysql, подзапрос

Есть таблица постов post от пользователей такого вида:

```
post_id: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

user_id: 1, 1, 2, 1, 3

status: 0, 0, 1, 2, 1
```

**Задача:** Вывести количество постов всего и количество постов, прошедших модерацию (где статус 1 или 2) по каждому юзеру.

Я пишу такого типа запрос:

```
select user_id, count(post_id) as 'all_posts', (select count(post_id)
from post where status in (1,2)) as 'approved'
from post
group by user_id
```

но (внезапно), подсчёт всех постов проходит норм, а подзапрос генерит одно число и копирует его по всем юзерам. Т.е. я понимаю что так и должно быть, но не понимаю как сделать чтобы подзапрос отрабатывал каждый раз свою строку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mySql  позволяет просуммировать булевы значения, автоматически преобразовывая false в 0 и true в 1. Так что в данном случае подзапрос вам просто не нужен

```
select user_id, count(post_id) as 'all_posts', sum(status <> 0) as 'approved'
from `likes`
group by user_id
```

Comment: Там просто еще статус 2 есть, а в боевой таблице там вообще их штук 10, нужны условно 1,2,3,4,5,6 а 0,7,8,9,10 не нужны

Comment: если именно так, то (status>0 and status<7) или, особенно если вперемешку, (status in (1,2,3,4,5,6))

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо! :)